# Select Form Material UI, cannot override placeholder

Tags: javascript, styles, overriding, material-ui

I'm here cause I cannot override my SelectionForm. I want to Change the color of the placeHolder into the image from red to another color. On material ui Docs I not find any properties or props to change the color.. Can someone help me?

[image]

I'm using this code

```
<div className="row">
            {
                Object.keys(FILTRO_AGENZIA_MAPPER).map((key5: string, w: number) =>
                    <div  className="col-sm-2" key={key5 + w} style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                        <Field name={FILTRO_AGENZIA_MAPPER[key5] || key5}
                               component={renderSelectField}
                               key={key5 + w}
                               label={FILTRO_AGENZIA_MAPPER[key5]}>
                            {
                                Object.keys(FILTRO_AGENZIA_VALUES).map((key6: string, y: number) =>
                                    <MenuItem key={key6 + y} value={FILTRO_AGENZIA_VALUES[key6] || key6}>
                                        {FILTRO_AGENZIA_VALUES[key6] || key6}
                                    </MenuItem>)
                            }
                        </Field>
                    </div>
                )}
        </div>



export const renderSelectField: React.FunctionComponent = ({label, children}: TextFieldProps): any => {
    return (
        <FormControl fullWidth={true}>
            <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
            <Select>
                {children}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to display this.

Comment: What library is the `Field` component from? It would help if you could provide a simple [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces this.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [`error` css class](https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/#css), take a look at [this](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#shorthand) code example.

Comment: Yep! this Can be a solution but overrinding as you says not working. I need to modify the css of my theme in this way "    },
            error:{
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            }
and I don't know what is the property of that placeorder